# What's the dependency for GcmTaskService (GCM)?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

What dependency can I put in my build.gradle file so that I can use Google's `GcmTaskService` (and/or other GCM features)?

I would prefer to use the specific dependency and not to use the generic Google Play Services dependency: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I was looking for: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'`

Source that includes all the different specific Google Play Services packages: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup